# How to fix error using Kafka-node in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apache-kafka

Anyone encounter this error using kafka-node in vue.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
at Object.inherits (app.js:143477:46)
at ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/wrapper/BrokerReadable.js (app.js:85751:6)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:221491:42)
at ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/wrapper/BrokerWrapper.js (app.js:85806:22)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:221491:42)
at ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js (app.js:81658:23)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:221491:42)
at ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/producerStream.js (app.js:83390:21)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:221491:42)
at ./node_modules/kafka-node/kafka.js (app.js:77699:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is an event streaming thing (usually wired to a database somehow I guess).
Node.js is a backend runtime.

Both of those things are totally unrelated to a frontend like VueJS (especially if not using anything like Nuxt), so you're probably mistaking the fact that you can mix both.

We don't have more context but as of right now, just reading the title indicates something totally not compatible right from the start.